# Sum of the components

Tags: reactjs

I need to get a suma of the total amount of customers, the customer amount is entered through a button onClick and in total I have three shops all as different components, that are then called, how do I do it?

Component Shop

```
 render(props) {
    //@@viewOn:private
    //const [isOn, setIsOn] = useState(props.isOn);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    
      
    //@@viewOff:private

    //@@viewOn:interface
    //@@viewOff:interface

    //@@viewOn:render

    return (
      <>
        <div> 
        <h1>Kaufland</h1>
        <p>Customers {count}</p>
        <Uu5Elements.Button onClick={() => setCount((current) => current + 1)< 10}>+1</Uu5Elements.Button>
    </div> 
      </>
    
    //@@viewOff:render
  )},
});

//@@viewOn:exports
export { Shop };
export default Shop;
//@@viewOff:exports
```

and then I have pretty much copy-pastes of the component 2 more times for 2 more shops, fe.:

Component Shop2

```
render(props) {
    //@@viewOn:private
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    //@@viewOff:private

    //@@viewOn:interface
    //@@viewOff:interface

    //@@viewOn:render
   

    return (
      <>
        <div> 
        <h1>Lidl</h1>
        <p>Customers {count}</p>
        <Uu5Elements.Button onClick={() => setCount((current) => current + 1)< 10}>+1</Uu5Elements.Button>
    </div> 
      </>
    
    //@@viewOff:render
    )},
  });

//@@viewOn:exports
export { Shop2 };
export default Shop2;
//@@viewOff:exports
```

And then I cant piece together how to get the amount of the Shop and add it to the amount of the Shop2...

```
return (
  <>
    <RouteBar />
  <div className={Css.mainContainer()}>
  <div>{currentTime.toLocaleString("cs")}</div>
      <h1>Total Customers</h1>
      <Total sum={Shop + Shop2 />
      <Shop />
      <Shop2 />
  </div>
  </>
);
```

Comment: Lift the state up into parent that renders the shop and manage it there. Plus with such similar shop component, you could probably make them one component and render them dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You need to `define the state in the common parent component of the two shop components` ([Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)) so that data can be shared through props. I created an example for your reference:

*Parent.js*

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import Shop1 from "./Shop1";
import Shop2 from "./Shop2";

const Parent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Sum: {count}</h1>
      <Shop1 setCount={setCount} />
      <Shop2 setCount={setCount} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

*Shop1.js*

```js
const Shop1 = ({ setCount }) => {
  const add = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  };

  return <button onClick={add}>Click</button>;
};

export default Shop1;
```

*Shop2.js*

```js
const Shop2 = ({ setCount }) => {
  const add = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  };

  return <button onClick={add}>Click</button>;
};

export default Shop2;
```

*App.js*

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Parent from "./Parent";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

View the [online example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-glitter-dwwpn2?file=/src/App.js) here.